Meaning of 輕巧 in 在小鐘如鈴般輕巧的聲響中，我想著我的兒子
在小鐘如鈴般輕巧的聲響中，我想著我的兒子
This sentence sets up the ambience of the narrator thinking about their son. In other words 在小鐘如鈴般輕巧的聲響中 has a literary quality to it. The meaning is roughly the sounds of a small clock ringing like a bell, and that sound is described by 輕巧.
I know 輕 means light, so the sound is light and not heavy.
巧 means something along having quick wits.
輕巧 as a phrase means light (denoting speed?) and quick-witted or easy (describing an action).
As you can see, I fail to understand how being light/fast and quick-witted can be used to describe a sound. Any help would be appreciated!

What's the origin of this piece of text?

輕 qīng = light (not heavy); small; gentle, soft
巧 qiǎo = clever, skillful, artful (-> deceitful); deft, glib (of hand or tongue); timely, opportunely
輕巧 = light, handy; deft, with grace; simple, easy; nimble, agile
(the word has a kind of onomatopoeic quality; but it's pretty old) - suggests something that is small, light and elegant, graceful -- in sounds like a pleasant, perhaps fast, light tinkling?

我想著我的兒子, (I keep thinking of my son), is because Chinese babies often wear ankle bracelets with tiny bells attached which give off a pleasant, tinkling sound, so that the parents know the baby is crawling about, and also there is a belief that anklets hold protective qualities, bringing luck and fortune to the baby. Thus on hearing 小鐘如鈴般輕巧的聲響中, the author thought, or is reminded of, his / her son and the gentle tinkling sound of the ankle bracelet.

It means a very faint and delicate sound like the sound of windchimes in a breeze.

One of the definitions of 巧 is:
(5) 巧妙;精妙 [artistic;smart;adept] https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%B7%A7
Usually, 輕巧 is explained as "light and handy", even after applying the definition of "artistic", this word does not seem to easily comprehend. Instead, I think the author meant to say "輕靈", for the word "靈" has the meaning of "spirit, soul; spiritual", then 輕巧的聲響 can be translated as "light spiritual sound" that accompanies her in thinking/remembrance of her son.

Which word sounds better to you 輕靈 or 輕巧? I'm not a native Chinese speaker, so I don't have a good feel for this. But would 輕靈 perhaps also suggest something a bit more melancholic? Or even mournful (惆怅)? Somehow it makes me think of 靈堂... Do you (if you are a native speaker) have the same associations?

輕巧 is usually used to describe flexible and swift body movement, such as 輕巧的身手/ 舞姿/步履... No, neither 輕 nor 靈 implies "mournful( 惆怅)" but "light" and "spiritually".   Here, 靈 points to the spiritual connection between the mother and the faraway son.

It's remarkable that ChatGPT gets this right - the subtle differences between 輕巧  and  輕靈. Quote: "轻灵 conveys a sense of grace, delicacy, and elegance, which matches the soft, ethereal sound and light movement of the tiny bells as they jingle on a bracelet. It emphasizes the beauty and gentle nature of the sound, as well as the refined, almost magical feeling associated with such an object."

Quote: "Why not 轻巧:
轻巧 focuses more on practicality, lightness, and efficiency, which might be suitable for describing the design of the bracelet (if you were emphasizing how it is cleverly made or easy to wear), but it lacks the poetic or delicate connotation that 轻灵 carries. For something as aesthetic and gentle as the sound of tiny bells, 轻灵 is a more fitting choice."

在 。。。中：in
小鐘：small bell
鈴般：bell-like, silvery
輕巧: light, not heavy
聲響: sound
小鐘如鈴般輕巧的聲響
想著: think of, miss
在小鐘如鈴般輕巧的聲響中，我想著我的兒子
In the silvery light soud of the bell,
我想著我的兒子
I am reminded of my son.
